# Remoting SSL Connection in JBoss AS7

Tags: java, ssl, jboss, jboss7.x

I am trying to achieve SSL connection between Java client and JBoss AS 7 while accessing Remoting EJB's.

I have added following properties in client application:

```
jboss.naming.client.remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=true
jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_STARTTLS=true
```

However there is no SSL handshaking between server and client.

Please guide how can i achieve SSL connection in JBoss AS7

Comment: Take a look in http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=2176